# Need query in oracle using group by and counts for the below

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like the below.

```
12-APR-19 06.48.08.883000 PM,AWSA
12-APR-19 06.48.41.208000 PM,
12-APR-19 07.24.55.697334 PM,ER
11-APR-19 08.58.34.835000 AM,AWSA
10-APR-19 08.10.38.675052 PM,ER
19-APR-19 09.48.14.597000 AM,
```

.........

Have tried the below query.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(register_date,'DD-MON-YY') || ',' || 
   reg_type || ',' || COUNT(*)
FROM po_ta_oam_customer
WHERE register_date >= '01-APR-19' AND register_date < '08-APR-19'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(register_date,'DD-MON-YY'),
         reg_type
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(register_date,'DD-MON-YY');
```

I am getting the result like below.

```
 1-Apr-19   AWSA    1222
 1-Apr-19   ER  34
 1-Apr-19       2556
 2-Apr-19   AWSA    1062
 2-Apr-19   ER  22
 2-Apr-19       2431
 3-Apr-19   AWSA    1037
 3-Apr-19   ER  33
 3-Apr-19       2521
 4-Apr-19   AWSA    920
 4-Apr-19   ER  36
 4-Apr-19       2359
 5-Apr-19   AWSA    832
 5-Apr-19   ER  20
 5-Apr-19       2091
 6-Apr-19   AWSA    476
 6-Apr-19   ER  18
 6-Apr-19       1673
 7-Apr-19   AWSA    50
 7-Apr-19   ER  15
 7-Apr-19       1555
```

But I am trying to get the result as following.

```
   Date     AWSA    ER  Blanks
 1-Apr-19   1222    34  2556
 2-Apr-19   1062    22  2431
 3-Apr-19   1037    33  2521
 4-Apr-19   920     36  2359
 5-Apr-19   832     20  2091
 6-Apr-19   476     18  1673
 7-Apr-19   50      15  1555
```

Comment: give the column names in the sample data and what are blanks coumn??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a variation on Barbaros's answer.  But I recommend:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(register_date, 'DD-MON-YY') as "Date",
       SUM(CASE WHEN reg_type = 'AWSA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as AWSA,
       SUM(CASE WHEN reg_type = 'ER' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ER,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(reg_type) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Blank
FROM po_ta_oam_customer
WHERE register_date >= DATE '2019-04-01' AND
      register_date < DATE '2019-04-08'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(register_date, 'DD-MON-YY')             
ORDER BY MAX(register_date);
```

Notes:

- The date constants are input as date constants rather than strings.  Oracle supports this and it makes the query clearer.
- All data from April 7th is included.
- The `ORDER BY` will work for periods that span more than one month.
- The calculation of `Blank` works for any number of spaces or a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional aggregation`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(register_date,'DD-MON-YY')              as "Date",
       COUNT( CASE WHEN reg_type = 'AWSA' THEN 1 END ) as AWSA,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN reg_type = 'ER'   THEN 1 END ) as ER,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN reg_type = '  '   THEN 1 END ) as "Blank"
  FROM po_ta_oam_customer
 WHERE register_date BETWEEN '01-APR-19' AND '07-APR-19'
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(register_date,'DD-MON-YY')             
 ORDER BY "Date";
```

P.S. I'm not sure about the length of space characters in `reg_type = '  '` collation that's constructing the `"Blank"` column, seems has 2 char. length and I left as so.